# PHP - HTTPS SSL Applying

Tags: php, windows, security, ssl

How would I apply SSL HTTPS to my PHP Login system. My login system is basic here is how it goes:

Fetches session and user then checks if its correct. I'll need some kind of SSL/HTTPS checking.

Any examples?

Comment: Are you asking for how to set up a web server to use SSL?  Or maybe if there's a way for a PHP application to check the connection type to see if it's SSL?

Comment: Basically I am going to self assign myself a SSL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question makes little sense. SSL is a secure transport layer, but its operation is totally transparent to PHP.

Everything that worked before you had SSL should work the same way it does *with* SSL. All the authentication and encryption/decryption is done automatically for you.

See:

- [How SSL works](http://www.verisign.com/ssl/ssl-information-center/how-ssl-security-works/) (from Verisign)
- [Step by Step: Configuring SSL Under Apache](http://tim.oreilly.com/pub/a/onlamp/2008/03/04/step-by-step-configuring-ssl-under-apache.html)
- [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) (if you run into problems configuring the server)

Comment: I am basically going to assign myself a SSL cert, I want it to work with my login system.

Comment: @Raymond If you set up SSL correctly, it should work without any changes to your PHP code - at least the login logic. You might want to make the script force the user to use SSL on login however, but just try to make SSL work in the first place.

Comment: I saw some things to do with HTTPS in someones coding before on there login system. Just was not sure what it is. Do I need that?

Comment: @Raymond You'll need to be more specific. What "things"?

Comment: HTTPS: something like this "function redirectToHTTPS()
{
  if($_SERVER['HTTPS']!="on")
  {
     $redirect= "https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
     header("Location:$redirect");
  }
"

Comment: @Raymond Yeah, that forces the page to use HTTPS instead of HTTP. But I would focus on getting HTTPS to work in the first place for now (that can be a bit tricky)

Comment: @Ray What server are you using? (eg: Apache, IIS, etc)

Comment: @Ray See the second link on my answer